# First problem to be considered np complete?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, np

What is the first problem that was demonstrated to be NP-Complete?

Comment: SAT$\quad\quad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the original paper of Cook online: [The complexity of theorem-proving procedures](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?coll=GUIDE&dl=GUIDE&id=805047). You can also find Levin's paper in Russian: [Universal Sequential Search Problems](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=ppi&paperid=914&option_lang=eng). A translation can be found in the appendix to a historical survey by Trakhtenbrot: [A Survey of Russian Approaches to *Perebor* (Brute-Force Search) Algorithms](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~christos/classics/a4384.pdf). You can even find Karp's [Reducibility Among Combinatorial Problems](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs172/karp.pdf).

Cook showed that the set of DNF tautologies (i.e., the complement of SAT) is NP-complete in his sense (oracle reducibility). Karp mentioned that SAT is actually NP-complete with respect to many-one reductions. Levin's paper mentions six different problems, but has no proofs (as was customary).